# How to prevent the other looking to your SWC library?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flex3, flex4

Thank you for your interesting in my question. I hope I would not waste your time too much.

I am going to publish my Adobe Flex library to sell in commercial, but I don't need anyone can open my SWC file and study the code in there. I see Adobe Flex library can prevent this activity. How could I do this too?

Comment: Good question. Also if you would make a flash client which uses a public WebService with hash-key based authentication, there is always a possibility that someone would get your secret key from the application.

Answer (score 0):

Security in every practical case (not just this one) is about putting more obstacles in the attackers way than they can deal with, protecting SWCs is no exception.

[Some companies](http://www.amayeta.com/software/swfencrypt/) allow encryption of SWFs (amongst other things), but I doubt anything is utterly foolproof to a determined hacker.

Other companies, such as Jeff Houser's Flextras take a totally different approach, not protecting the source but increasing value through other means (and now I've mentioned his name, the beast is surely summoned)